# What does the phrase "get three assists with your player" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrases

Here is a sentence from a football game app's description:

> In the game you will be asked **to get three assists with your player**.

I know the meaning of the word [assist](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assist_(football)), however the meaning of the said phrase is not clear to me.

It's an app, so the players here mean the digital players who are controlled by the human player.

Comment: Could you share what your definition of assist is? Just to be sure that we are all on the same page.

Comment: Also Football or American Football?

Comment: @katatahito https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assist_(football)

Comment: @katatahito It's football.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more context, and with a general understanding of how video games are set up here is my understanding:

**Get** is being used here to mean achieve or accomplish.

**with your player** would refer to the fact that "You" are in fact not actually participating in the football game, but rather "You" are controlling a "Player." Therefore "Player" is sort of a device that you are using to achieve the "assists."

As in the Wikipedia article you linked **assist** is a countable noun that is "given" or "awarded" by the scorekeepers (or other?). Some usual verb that describes the receiving of a countable noun because of an accomplishment are "recieve" (obviouly), "get" or "earn."

Therefore the phrase is saying the game will ask **You/Your-Player to perform an assist three times." The following sentence is likely what will happen after you accomplish this task - unlock a trophy, new mode, proceed to the next training stage, etc.

Hope this helps!